# Translate front-end templates in SailsJS

Tags: internationalization, sails.js, client-side

I'm no able to translate client-side templates in sails.
Docs says:

If you'd prefer not to use an external internationalization library, you can actually reuse Sails' i18n support to help you get your translated templates to the browser. If you want to use Sails to internationalize your client-side templates, put your front-end templates in a subdirectory of your app's /views folder.

- In development mode, you should retranslate and precompile your templates each time the relevant stringfile or template changes using grunt-contrib-watch, which is already installed by default in new Sails projects.
- In production mode, you'll want to translate and precompile all templates on lift(). In loadtime-critical scenarios (e.g. mobile web apps) you can even upload your translated, precompiled, minified templates to a CDN like Cloudfront for further performance gains.

but at the and, when i use client-side template with window.JST global i'm getting:

jst.js:82 Uncaught ReferenceError: __ is not defined
    at Object.JST.views/templates/archiveListItemNoResults.ejs (jst.js:82)

Comment: If you get this error on client side, this means you are trying to execute server side code on the client side. In sails documentation it is clearly said that you need to **precompile** your views, not serve them with some code inside them. And for production you need to do it before you lift the app.

Comment: yeah, i read that, but i'm not sure how to precompile client-side templates/views. Can you guide me to the right approach?

Comment: I've never done this. I think in the App,js file where your app is getting lifted you need firstto execute the translating part and copy each translated template in the corresponding view subfolder. Then, when this job is finished, lift the app.